# In S04E10 of "The Flash" who is "Kevin" that Marlize DeVoe refers to in her court testimony?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In the TV series *The Flash*, S04E10 ("[The Trial of The Flash](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trial_of_The_Flash)") who is "Kevin" that Marlize DeVoe refers to in her court testimony?

> The Flash (2014) s04e10 Episode (2018) Script
>   [The Trial of The Flash](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-flash-2014&episode=s04e10)

In her testimony in court for "The Trial of The Flash (Barry Allen)":

> Marlize is asked: "And what prompted the restraining order?"
>   She replies: "My husband has had advancing ALS. I was alone with Kevin most of the time. ..."

Her husband's name is "Clifford DeVoe", and the other person she is acquainted with is named "Dominic Lanse". Who is this "Kevin"?

I checked (as far as I can tell) other cast members, by their character names and their "real" names, and I can't find this person. Did she (or the script) make a mistake? or did I miss a detail somewhere about this person named Kevin?

Comment: She actually says: _"I was alone with __Clifford__ most of the time ..."_

Comment: I think its mistake in the script, I don't remember the line at all

Comment: I downloaded the subtitles for this episode and indeed it says Kevin. Will check the episode again... Maybe in the midst of her tears, she pronounced Clifford as Kevin? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The clip can be watched on Youtube __[here](https://youtu.be/47xXUnr__rI?t=89)__. To me she clearly says ___"Clifford"___.

Comment: @Oliver_C - The first URL I included has the script for that episode, it also says "Kevin". I listened to the video you linked to. At the point where she says the name, it might be a tiny bit garbled, so sometimes it doesn't sound exactly like "Kevin", but after listening to her say the name at least 20 times, the vast majority of the times, it sounds to me like she says "Kevin". And if you turn on captions for that video, it also says "Kevin".  ==>

Comment: ==> So, it sounds like it's a mistake in the script, or in her recital. But it is a little odd, that at that exact moment, and seemingly nowhere else, her voice is a bit garbled (to me).

Comment: @KevinFegan That woman has to speak and cry man! Give her some space :D But seriously though, she speaks Clifford too fasty (forgive the pun) that it spells like Kevin. Just like you, I have been hearing her speak for nearly 10 times...

Comment: @KevinFegan - She says Clifford several more times during the whole scene, do you always hear "Kevin"?. - And what you linked to is __not the script__, it's a __transcript__ written by fans.

Comment: @Oliver_C - Hence, my question. I expect someone who has had access to the actual script, might at some point be able to answer.

Comment: @Oliver_C - the other times that she said "Clifford", where it sounded like she said "Clifford", I heard "Clifford". As far as I know, it was only the one time that I thought she said "Kevin".

Comment: @AnkitSharma - What was the point of the edit? It was fine before your edit. I don't think it was an appropriate edit, but I'm not sure (yet) if it should be rolled back. I prefer to fully spell out "Season" and "Episode" so people searching will more easily find this. Spelling it as a single word: "S04E10" without separating them like "S04  E10" or "S04  Ep10" or even "S04-Ep10" seems to possibly hinder searching. Am I missing something, or would it be appropriate for me to go through the movies.SE site and change all occurrences of "SxxEyy" to "Season" and "Episode"?  (I guess it wouldn't)

Comment: @KevinFegan I started the edit due to the missing tags (arrowverse) but later I changed the title to make it little shorter for good readability and then kept S0XE0X for consistency in body.